# Solving basic arithmetic modulo

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I have no idea to solve these 3 questions because i only seen the question include with equal sign. ex) $a\equiv r \mod n$

$(-2)^5+ 7\mod 6$

$15-11\cdot12\mod12$

$4\cdot13+23\cdot2\mod15$

Comment: Do you know the basic congruence theory? It is an oral calculation.

Comment: The question tells you to find the remainder when $(-2)^5+7$ is divided by  $6$, and $\dots$ (similar statement for other $2$ questions). Now, can you solve this?

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know how to do it but now i could solve the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll show you how to do the first one:

$$(-2)^5 + 7=-32+7=-25 = \color{blue}{-5\cdot 6}+\color{red}{5} \\ \implies (-2)^5 + 7 \equiv \color{red}{5} \mod \color{blue}{6}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate it

Comment: No problem. :-)